# What is the difference between a ElementTree and an Element? (python xml)

Tags: python, xml, element, elementtree

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, dump

elem = Element('1')
sub = SubElement(elem, '2')
tree = ElementTree(elem)

dump(tree)
dump(elem)
```

In the code above, dumping tree (which is an ElementTree) and dumping elem (which is an Element) results in the same thing.  Therefore I am having trouble determining what the difference is between the two.

Answer (score 4):

> dumping tree (which is an ElementTree) and dumping elem (which is an Element) results in the same thing.

[`dump()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1151) function works the same for `ElementTree` and `Element` because it was intentionally made to behave this way:

```
def dump(elem):
    # debugging
    if not isinstance(elem, ElementTree):
        elem = ElementTree(elem)
    elem.write(sys.stdout)
    ...
```

> I am having trouble determining what the difference is between the two.

[`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects) is a wrapper class that corresponds to the "entire element hierarchy" providing serialization functionality - dumping and loading the tree. [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects), on the other hand, is a much "bigger" class that defines the `Element` interface.

Comment: Can you think of a good way to illustrate the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

The `ElementTree` wrapper class is used to read and write XML files [[ref](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#reading-and-writing-xml-files)]. Most `ElementTree` apis are simple wrappers around the root `Element` [[ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects)]. Simply put, `ElementTree` wraps the root `Element` (for convenience) and provides methods to serialize/deserialize the entire tree. Hence `parse()` belongs to `ElementTree` where `iter()` is a simple wrapper.

Then there are helper functions like `iterparse` and `dump()` in the `xml.etree.ElementTree` namespace. `dump()` writes a full xml doc to stdout [[ref](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1165)] whereas `iterparse` spits out `Element`s iteratively. Contrast `parse()`, which returns an `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` object and hence a complete hierarchy, to `iterparse()`, which returns an iterator[[1](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#reading-and-writing-xml-files)].

[1](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#reading-and-writing-xml-files) There might be some confusion between `xml.etree.ElementTree` package namespace and `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` class name.

Comment: Both `Element` and `ElementTree` objects have an `iter()` method. What do you mean when you say "`iter()` is a simple wrapper"?

Comment: @mzjn See `iter()` [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L391) for `Element` vs `iter()` [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L611) for `ElementTree`.

Comment: I still don't understand. What does it mean for a method to be a "simple wrapper"?

Comment: @mzjn A wrapper is usually a function that wraps another function, mostly for convenience or for presenting a consistent interface.

Comment: What other method/function does `iter()` wrap? And how does that help in understanding the difference between Element and ElementTree objects?